# dedupe rule using birth date is not working using drupal

Tags: duplicate-contacts

A dedupe rule using birth date is not working with drupal CMS. I receive the message "unknown error, please contact your administrator". The rule is working well in WordPress

Comment: In our installation with Drupal it is not working. Maybe it depends on the version. We use the 5.9.1

Answer (score 1):

This sounds odd since it should not be CMS related. I tested on dmaster - set up a DoB based rule, it worked

Link is below but will be removed when site next rebuilds in a few hours

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/dedupefind?reset=1&action=update&rgid=8

Is it possible you made an error setting up your Rule?

[image]

[image]

[image]